# string formula not evaluated in global environment?

Tags: r

The string formula in the loop throws an error with `standardize()`, whereas the non-loop versions do not. Environment issue?

```
library(arm)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=runif(50),
                 x1=runif(50),
                 x2=runif(50))


# does not work
  for (i in c("x1", "x2")) {
    f <- paste("y", i, sep="~")
    m0 <- lm(f, data=df)
    m0z <- arm::standardize(m0)
  }
  formula(m0)
  #y ~ x1
  #<environment: 0x140745e40>

# works
  m1 <- lm(y ~ x1, data=df)
  m1z <- arm::standardize(m1)

  m2 <- lm(y ~ x2, data=df)
  m2z <- arm::standardize(m2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important that the formula is actually substituted in the `lm` object:

```
for (i in list(quote(x1), quote(x2))) {
    f <- bquote(y ~ .(i))
    m0 <- eval(bquote(lm(.(f), data=df)))
    m0z <- arm::standardize(m0)
}
```

Comment: Hm. Why is that? `lm` shouldn’t use NSE.

Comment: Trying to understand how `lm` stores its call and the associated environment hurts my brain. I can't say if what it does can be called NSE, but I wouldn't call it standard evaluation.

Comment: Yeah, I see. To be honest, this looks like a bug. Although I can’t see how a bug could have slipped past in such a central, frequently-used function.

Comment: There are probably dozens of questions on SO where functions using an `lm` object can't find variables. `lm` is super-fancy. It's hard for depending functions to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to not use string formulas, but rather to construct a formula from an expression, and evaluate that:

```
f = eval(bquote(y ~ .(as.name(i))))
```

This works because `f` will be constructed in the current environment.

Alternatively, just call `as.formula(f)` manually instead of passing the naked `f` to `lm`; however, I always dislike going the detour via strings. This is an anti-pattern known as [stringly typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. For `as.formula(f)`, do you mean: `m0 <- lm(as.formula(f), data=df)`?

Comment: @EricGreen Yes.

Comment: I also get the same error with `f = eval(bquote(y ~ .(as.name(i))))` substituted for `f <- paste("y", i, sep="~")` in the original example.

Comment: @EricGreen I can’t reproduce that, it works for me. I get an unrelated error though (“arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 0”).

Comment: Ah, I see now, the error is related to your problem. But apparently not to whether or not the formula has an environment. Hmm.